# Lenovo Thinkpad drivers for WIndows 11 (should I use update to Windows 10 drivers?)

Tags: drivers, windows-11, thinkpad, lenovo-vantage

1. When I bought my Lenovo Thinkpad x380 Yoga a few years ago I
   installed Windows 10 on it.
2. A few months ago Windows recommended me
   to update to Windows 11 (it is ready for an update), but I didn't
   update.
3. A few days ago my SSD died. So I replaced it with a new one and installed Windows 11 on the new SSD.

Lenovo Vantage and Windows Update both do not suggest me the latest drivers. E.g., I've seen that on my devise BIOS version 1.35 is installed, but when I go to https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x380-yoga/20lj/downloads/driver-list/ it tells me that the latest BIOS version is 1.36 for Windows-10. Most of the drivers on this webpage say that they are for Windows 10 when you click on details. Only a few of them explicitly mention that they supprt Windows 11.

Can it be that the older BIOS version 1.35 is more compatible with WIndows-11 than the older latest version 1.36?
Does Lenovo Vantage only update the drivers that explicitly mention compatibility with WIndows 11? Which version do I have installed for drivers wihtout any version explicitly mentioning the compatibility with Windows 11? Some very old version maybe?

I would have expected that for every device of my Laptop the latest version of the driver should be compatible with Windows-11 since Windows recommended me to upgrade.

After windows update, Lenovo Vantage and the Lenovo Service bridge automatic check on https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x380-yoga/ all told me that there are no updates available, my toucpad still did not support basic features such as two finger scrolling. Only after I manually installed the latest version of the driver (from 2 years ago which says Windows-10 but does not mention WIndows 11) from https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x380-yoga/ my touchpad started to work properly. (Unfortunately I have not checked which version was installed before.)
I am not sure if this was just some strange problem with this specific driver or if there is a general problem of the update policy of Lenovo Vantage and Windows update?

Comment: As far as drivers go, there is no difference between Windows 10 and 11. The [Lenovo Vantage page](https://support.lenovo.com/bg/en/solutions/ht505081-lenovo-vantage-using-your-pc-just-got-easier) says it supports Windows 11 - are you using the same version as on the page (from the Microsoft Store)?

Comment: Lenovo keeps its drivers in the Microsoft Catalog so that Microsoft Update can update drivers. That happened with my Lenovo Laptop that I got in 2022. But now System Update (or Lenovo Vantage) works as well.

Comment: @harrymc Lenovo Vantage is compatbile with WIdnows 11, but Lenovo Vantage does not offer me the latest version of the drivers (I think because the drivers [falsely?] claim to be only compatible with Windows 10)

Comment: If you're using the Microsoft Store version, then your explanation is probably correct. You should either wait for a correction, or signal the bug to Lenovo Support. In any case, using Windows 10 drivers is perfectly safe if they fix some problem, otherwise let Windows Update do the job.

Comment: I bought my Lenovo Thinkpad x380 Yoga a few years ago  .....  Also make sure it is a generation 8 or 9 CPU.  I have had a few instances of drivers updating and nothing in Vantage or System Update. It takes some time. Some of this is still a work in progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as drivers go, there is no difference between Windows 10 and 11.

If you're using the latest Lenovo Vantage version from the
Microsoft Store version, then this is a Lenovo bug.
You could either wait for a correction or signal the bug to Lenovo Support.

In the meantime, using Windows 10 drivers is perfectly safe if they fix
some problem, otherwise let Windows Update do the job.

Comment: Yes, I use the latest version of Lenovo Vantage from the Windows Store.